# Knockout text databind erasing part of my Markup

Tags: data-binding, knockout.js

I'm facing a small problem regarding Knockout JS databind on a span. I want to bind a number alongside a percentage symbol. My original HTML markup is this one:

```
<span>10</span><span>%</span>
```

Then, I'd try to make the number dynamic with the following expression (I'm forfeiting the JS as it works corrctly and I don't think it's necessary for my case):

```
<span data-bind="text: cartTotalPrice" /><span>%</span>
```

Misteriously, the  that contains the % symbol disappears, only displaying the binded number. But then if I do the following, the number and the symbol are correctly displayed:

```
<span data-bind="text: cartTotalPrice() + '%'" />
```

Why does this happen? Is it normal?

Thanks.

Comment: Aren't you missing a closing " on the line that is not working, say it should be data-bind="text: cartTotalPrice"? In the second example with the € it works probably because you have correctly set the closing ".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the problem is that you are not closing your span tag. Use an explicit closing `</span>`.

`<span data-bind="text: cartTotalPrice"></span><span>%</span>`

Comment: I'm sorry, I corrected it, I just posted it incorrectly. Yeah it was correctly closed, otherwise Visual studio would had raised an alert to me due to wrong format.

Comment: Your updated version does not match what I wrote. It is still using a self closing tag.

Comment: Wow, using a explicit close tag instead of a self-closing solved the issue. Thank you very much! Isn't that weird though?

Comment: @DavidJiménezMartínez [`span`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/span) always requires the closing tag. Browsers are just more forgiving than knockout.